# Different randomForest results via caret and randomForest package using seeds on train control

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, caret

After following the questions

- [Different results from randomForest via caret and the basic randomForest package](http://google.com)
- [Fully reproducible parallel models using caret](http://adsgg)

Below there is a reproducible example using IRIS dataset where I can't reproduce the random forest model when not using caret's train function.

```
library(doParallel); library(caret)

#create a list of seed, here change the seed for each resampling
set.seed(123)
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 11)#length is = (n_repeats*nresampling)+1
for(i in 1:10) seeds[[i]]<- sample.int(n=1000, 3) #(3 is the number of tuning parameter, mtry for rf, here equal to ncol(iris)-2)

seeds[[11]]<-sample.int(1000, 1)#for the last model

#control list
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', seeds = seeds, index=createFolds(iris$Species))

#run model in parallel
cl <- makeCluster(12, type="SOCK",outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)
model1 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)

model2 <- train(Species~., iris, method='rf', trControl=myControl)
stopCluster(cl)

#compare
all.equal(predict(model1, type='prob'), predict(model2, type='prob'))
```

...

```
 >[1] TRUE
```

...

```
# using the same seed as for model 2
set.seed(seeds[[11]])
model3 <- randomForest(Species~., iris, mtry = model2$bestTune$mtry)
all.equal(predict(model2, type='prob'),as.data.frame(predict(model3, type='prob')))
```

...

```
>[1] "Component “versicolor”: Mean relative difference: 0.3006435"
>[2] "Component “virginica”: Mean relative difference: 0.2400822"
```

- What am I missing ?  Is it possible to reproduce the random forest model returned by caret's train function?
- If not, can we train the final model in caret with different parameters ? such as importance and proximities flags to true ?

Comment: Removing the parallel (i.e. every line containing cl) makes the result reproducible

Comment: Sorry, but it is no so. Making it sequential does not make it reproducible.

Comment: Strange, it worked on my machine... I will give it another try on another computer...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out in the meantime.

So calling

```
predict(model1, type='prob')
```

or model2 for that matter, will evaluate the whole training data. It is the same as

```
predict(model2,type='prob') == predict(model2$finalModel, iris,type='prob')
```

Using the predict function on the random Forest model will evaluate the OOB data, so

```
predict(model2$finalModel, type='prob') == as.data.frame(predict(model3, type='prob'))
```

Which leads to

```
predict(model2$finalModel, iris,type='prob') == predict(model3,type='prob')
```

and this was what was missing when comparing the models results and assessing  for reproducibility.

I've left out the call to `all.equal` in the code above for clarity.